# Is tbody before thead valid

Tags: html, html-table

I have a simple table here where the tbody is before the thead

The table still works with the head above the body but is this valid and will this work in all modern browsers.

I'm doing it like this to solve a problem with a sticky header

```html
<table>
  
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>One</td>
      <td>Two</td>
      <td>Three</td>
    </tr>
  <tbody>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Header 1</th>
      <th>Header 2</th>
      <th>Header 3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
<table>
```

Comment: No. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table

Comment: The answers in this question are outdated if not wrong althogether https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49926153/is-tbody-before-thead-valid

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`<thead>`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/tables.html#the-thead-element) element after the [`<tbody>`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/tables.html#the-tbody-element) element **is not valid**. You can validate your HTML5 markup on the [HTML5-Validator](https://html5.validator.nu/). After validating, this error is shown:

> **Error:** Element `<thead>` not allowed as child of element `<table>` in this context.
>
> Contexts in which element `<thead>` may be used:
> As **a child of** a `<table>` element, **after any**  `<caption>`, and `<colgroup>` elements and **before any** `<tbody>`, `<tfoot>`, and  `<tr>` elements, but only if there are no other `<thead>` elements that are children of the `<table>` element.

Also care the content model of the [`<table>`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/tables.html#the-table-element) element:

> In this order: optionally a `<caption>` element, followed by zero or more `<colgroup>` elements, followed optionally by a `<thead>` element, followed by either zero or more `<tbody>` elements or one or more `<tr>` elements, followed optionally by a `<tfoot>` element, optionally intermixed with one or more script-supporting elements.

**So the order of the elements inside the `<table>` element matters.**

**The following HTML markup is valid HTML5:**

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Header 1</th>
      <th>Header 2</th>
      <th>Header 3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>One</td>
      <td>Two</td>
      <td>Three</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>One</td>
      <td>Two</td>
      <td>Three</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>One</td>
      <td>Two</td>
      <td>Three</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**Note:** You can also remove the closing tags `</thead>` and `</tbody>` in this case, because...

> A `<thead>` element's end tag can be omitted if the `<thead>` element is immediately followed by a `<tbody>` or `<tfoot>` element.

---

You can find all the above information on the [HTML specification](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/tables.html#the-thead-element).

Comment: you beat me to is. My answer is basically the same. I leave mine, because it contains the links to the spec. If you include these in your answer I would remove mine. +1 from me

Answer (score 0):

The original question has invalid html, @ttmt did not close tbody which makes the validator believe he has a thead inside a tbody, as a result of this the currently accepted answer is wrong.

Thead, Tbody and Tfoot can't be inside each other, but they **can come in any given order** inside the table tag as per current html5 specification

https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/tables.html#the-thead-element

Comment: In the linked spec it says thead can be used "As a child of a table element, after any caption, and colgroup elements and **before any tbody, tfoot, and tr elements**, but only if there are no other thead elements that are children of the table element."